# Filter by year and month when the datatype is varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I'm trying to run a query with a `WHERE` clause to filter out data by year and month but the issue is that the `CreateDate` column is of type `varchar`. I cannot change the data type in the table.

How can I use this query?

Am I casting it incorrectly? Do I need to Convert then apply `YEAR` and `MONTH`?

I'm not sure what to do.

This is the error I get from SQL Server:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE YEAR(CAST(SUBSTRING(CreateDate, 1, 4) AS datetime)) = 2021 
AND MONTH(CAST(SUBSTRING(CreateDate, 6, 2) AS datetime)) = 2 
AND ...
```

Column datatypes:

```
ID = INT
FirstName = varchar
Phone = int
CreateDate = varchar
```

[image]

Comment: Since your date is a varchar ... why not CreateDate like '2021-02%'

Comment: `the issue is that the CreateDate column is varchar` - why? And why don’t you fix it?

Comment: Once you've changed the data type, do not use functions on the column. Instead use a date range `WHERE CreateDate >= '20210201' AND CreateDate < '20210301'`

Comment: ^^ ... otherwise the query is [non-sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) which degrades query performance.

Comment: IMHO it would be better to use the time you spent now on this problem, to fix the real problem and alter the datatype. You might be able to get this one problem "fixed" but how long until the next problem arrives because of the wrong datatype ?

Comment: The reason that you are getting an error is that you are trying to convert just the year and the month to a date, i.e. `CAST(SUBSTRING(CreateDate, 1, 4) AS datetime))` --> `CAST('2022` AS datetime)`. Which will fail. If you actually need to convert this to a date, you can use `TRY_CONVERT(datetime, CreateDate)` (beware, that with `datetime` the format used is culture sensitive so could be yyyy-MM-dd or yyyy-DD-mm depending on your settings). But honestly, the best solution is as Aaron suggested, change your type. Next best is John's as it avoids conversion, so this would be 3rd choice.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `CAST` function incorrectly e.g. attempting `cast('02' as datetime)` will throw the specified error. Considering that the date is stored as string, you can use one of the following options (sorted by *expected* performance):

```
WHERE CreateDate LIKE '2021-02-%'
WHERE SUBSTRING(CreateDate, 1, 4) = '2021' AND SUBSTRING(CreateDate, 6, 2) = '02'
WHERE CAST(CreateDate AS DATE) >= '2021-02-01' AND CAST(CreateDate AS DATE) < '2021-03-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to nulls in your field as you might already know. This is how to fix it.

There are two approaches

1. **USING ISNULL()**

> ```
> SELECT *  
> FROM Table1  
> WHERE Year(cast(ISnull(CreateDate,'1753-01-01 00:00:00') as datetime))=2021
> --'1753-01-01 00:00:00' is the min date for datetime. ISNULL replaces NULLS with given value
> ```

2. **USING Where Clause**

> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM Test
> WHERE 
>   Createdate is not null and 
>   Year(cast(CreateDate as datetime))=2021
> ```